# How do I unequip grenades in DeusEx: Mankind Divided

Tags: ps4, deus-ex-mankind-divided

I keep on accidentally throwing grenades - more than a dozen instances, and I'm only eight hours into the game. I'd like to unequip all my grenades to prevent me from continually misthrowing them.

I know I can stick them in my cache, but that would make them unavailable when I need them. I still want them available in my inventory, just unequipped.

How do I unequip grenades in DeusEx: Mankind Divided?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. As far as I remember, you can only change grenade/mine types in your hand, the only way to not throw grenades accidentally is to not carry any, or change the binding that tosses a grenade.

Comment: As @Kaizerwolf mentioned, I think the best way to avoid this would be to change your grenade key binding

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm playing on the PS4 (just added that to the tags), so I can't change the binding for just the grenades without changing the entire control scheme to a different pre-set scheme. Thanks anyway, gents!